# Add field register page Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel-5.4

I'm looking to add a field on my registration page using Laravel Auth.
The basic user table contain the name, email, password.
I want to add an right field.

So I've eddited the `create_users_table.php` migration file to

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->string('password');
        $table->integer('right_id');
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

and my `registercontroller.php`to

```
protected function create(array $data)
{
    return User::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'right_id' => 0,
        'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
    ]);
}
```

But it doesn't works. I still have this error about `right_id`. Seem that the value is not send to the database.

Any fix/help?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use like this

```
  $data['right_id']  = 0;
  $data['password'] = bcrypt($data['password']);
  return User::create($data);
```

Comment: Works!!! But why insert method works when create doesn't? They may do the same things isn't it?

Comment: @Grégoire Martron : Try as I updated ans now your create method would also works.

Answer (score 4):

Have you specify your `right_id` in `User` model class like the code sample below? If you forget to declare the additional field in the `$fillable`, the value wont save into database.

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password', 'right_id'
    ];
}
```

Comment: Yes... protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password','right_id'
    ]; on user model

Comment: Can you check the log file, do it show any error when you do the save action?

Comment: Nope.
On the error webpage, we can notice that Model have the right_id field. But Builder doesn't have it...*

Answer (score 1):

on your registercontroller.php try to use

`'right_id' => '0'`, instead of `'right_id' => 0`,

If you just want to have '0' as a default value for 'right_id' you can also specify it on your creat_users_table.php like this

```
$table->integer('right_id')->default(0);
```

Then redo the migration

Comment: Works. But it's not really a proper way to implement it. The right_id value still not passed trought the registration... (I have hardcoded the value for debbuging)